# How does jQuery().change work with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input field which I add to html using ajax here:

```
function WritePrices(categories) {
    var strResult = "from: <input class=\"price\" type=\"text\" id=\"minCost\" value=\"" + categories.MinPrice + "\" />";
    strResult += "from: <input class=\"price\" type=\"text\" id=\"maxCost\" value=\"" + categories.MaxPrice + "\" />";
    $("#price-range").html(strResult);
}
```

And then I want to catch a moment when this input is changed by the user. That's why in the script I also have change method

```
jQuery("input#minCost").change(function () {
        //...
    });
```

But this method doesn't "hear" any changes to my input field. It hears changes only when my input field is created in html(not during in the script). what should I change to make jQuery seen changes to my input field?

Comment: [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is essential here!

Comment: use .on() Method for dynamically added elements http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `$("#price-range").on("change","#minCost",function(){});` will work for you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign event just after the creation. Please find working snippet below:

```js
function WritePrices(categories) {
    var strResult = "from: <input class=\"price\" type=\"text\" id=\"minCost\" value=\"" + categories.MinPrice + "\" />";
    strResult += "from: <input class=\"price\" type=\"text\" id=\"maxCost\" value=\"" + categories.MaxPrice + "\" />";
    $("#price-range").html(strResult);
    jQuery("input#minCost").change(function () {
        alert("working");
    });
}

var categories = {};
categories.MinPrice = 0.0;
categories.MaxPrice= 10;
WritePrices(categories);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `document` change pattern

```
$(document).on('change','input#minCost',function(){
  ...
});
```